# Authentication for a desktop app

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, authentication

First of all, I took a look to every related topic on her about this issue. However non of them was successful in answering my question fully.

Currently I am working on a desktop app, coded in C#/wpf, that requires MySQL connection both for authentication and storing user custom lists etc.

However, the problem is that apparently allowing everyone to remotely connect to MySQL db is not good practice. Also, my current host requires IPs to be whitelisted before they can connect to the db.

What are my options on this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look into creating a web service (SOAP), http web-api (REST) or some other middleware to abstract your data storage.

This has the benefits of:

- Allows you to move much of the business logic out of your desktop app and into middle ware
- Allows you to keep business logic out of sql which might be a bottleneck
- Allows you to update your business logic without redistributing your desktop app (easier if you don't have direct control of all the desktops).
- Allowing you to control authentication (many web servers have their own modules, method of authentication).  Your app would control access and access storage under it's own service account.
- Allows you to complete change your data storage (let's say in the future you store some in sql, some in mongodb, some in cloud storage - once again, without having to update all your desktops.
- Allows you to scale out your front ends and even possibly scale out your backend storage (for example, read/write DB replicas)

If you're already working with C#, then the new MVC4 web-api should be a good fit.  Read more here:

http://www.asp.net/web-api

If you go that route you could control access in your service and have your service access the database either via credentials in a connection string or if you use IIS, credentials on the application pool mapped to your site.

If you're shipping your desktop app (you're not hosting the DB) then you can also self host web-api in it's own exe if your customers don't want to install/manage IIS.

Finally, if your mysql is online, your middleware could be in the cloud (azure etc...)

Answer (score 2):

Create a web service, such as with WCF or MVC Web API where your app can pass through their credentials and authenticate.  I'd recommend https for transport security.