# User Type Authentication and Access Control in C#.net Desktop Application

Tags: c#, authentication, usertype

I have a small query.

I want to create user level authentication for a desktop application. Thats means, if:
1. Admin logs in, Admin get to see all options of the app
2. If user logs in, User gets to see only few details

My problem is I dont want to do this using a dropdown and choosing the User Type. I want to store the details in the database and once the user logs in, the new display window should show its contents according to the use type, i.e. Admin or User.

How can this be achieved. I am creating a Desktop application using C#.net.

Any help is appreciated.

Regards,
GenXCoders

Comment: Have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005027/authentication-for-a-desktop-app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the desktop program:

```
using System.Security.Principal;

....

string adLogon = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

That will get you the current user.

In the database, something like:

```
create table Users (
    ADLogon nvarchar(50), -- PK
    IsAdmin bit -- in SQL Server this is the boolean type
)
```

Lookup the current user is the database, get their permission level.

Comment: I am trying to make a project for my final year. It is a Attendence System. i want that, the desktop application should have only one login. If i enter the ADMIN details (of the HoD) then the HoD can check which all teacher and student are present, and also be able to add new teacher or student. if a teacher logs, then the teacher should be able to mark their attendence and the student attendence, and at the day end email a pdf file to the HoD that contains the days report.Rest is done.i want the modules to be called differently depending on the user.and that the login should remain the same.